# A truncated alternating sum of product of binomial terms

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

While solving a question I came across the following alternating sum; $C(j,n): = \sum\limits_{i=j}^{n} (-1)^{i}\binom{n+1}{i+1} \binom{i}{j}$ where $j$ and $n$ are integers with $n \geq j \geq 0$.

By hand I computed that $C(j, j+r) = (-1)^{j}$ for small positive integers $r$. I think that $C(j,n) = (-1)^j$ for any $n \geq j \geq 0$. But I couldn't prove it by induction or by using some other known identities. I would appreciate any suggestion or reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we  have *[Chu-Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*  in disguise.

> We     obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=j}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^i\binom{n+1}{i+1}\binom{i}{j}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-j}(-1)^{i+j}\binom{n+1}{i+j+1}\binom{i+j}{i}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^j\sum_{i=0}^{n-j}\binom{n+1}{n-j-i}\binom{-j-1}{i}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^j\binom{n-j}{n-j}\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^j}
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index  to start with $i=0$  and we use the   binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (2) we use the   binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we apply     *[Chu-Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=j}^{n}(-1)^i\binom{n+1}{i+1}\binom{i}{j}&=(-1)^j\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\binom{n+1}{i+1}[x^j](1-x)^i\\&=(-1)^j[x^j]\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{i+1}(x-1)^i\\&=(-1)^j[x^j]\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=(-1)^j.
\end{align}